# Firebase Nuxt Does Not Recognize 'location' Object When Trying to Run The Whole App With Firebase Emulator

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

My firebase `Nuxt` app was recently converted to SSR from SPA mode. It was all working fine in SPA mode but when I tried to convert it, it generated a lot of errors. I tried to solve them one by one and I'm stuck with the error `ReferenceError 'location' was not defined`. I want to run my emulator because I want to test my other functions if it is running completely in SSR mode.

```
import firebaseTmp from "firebase/app";
import firebaseErrorsJa from "~/plugins/firebaseErrorsJa";
import "firebase/storage";
import "firebase/firestore";
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/functions';

const config = process.env.firebaseConfig;

if (!firebaseTmp.apps.length) {
  firebaseTmp.initializeApp(config);
}
const db = firebaseTmp.firestore();
const functions = firebaseTmp.functions();
const firebase = firebaseTmp;
const firestore = firebaseTmp.firestore();
const storage = firebaseTmp.storage();
const auth = firebaseTmp.auth();
const firestoreTimestamp = firebaseTmp.firestore.Timestamp;
const serverTimestamp = firebaseTmp.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
const firebaseErrors = firebaseErrorsJa;

if (location.hostname === "localhost") {
  db.settings({
    host: "localhost:8000",
    ssl: false
  });

  functions.useEmulator("localhost", 5001);
  auth.useEmulator('http://localhost:9099/');
}

export { db, firebase, firestore, auth, storage, firestoreTimestamp, serverTimestamp, functions, firebaseErrors }
```

I imported almost all libraries but still it does not work.
TAKE NOTE: This only happens when it is in SSR mode. Does this mean that `location` does not work in SSR mode?

I tried to take away the chunk of code that has 'location' in it. It works perfectly well locally but when I try to run my other functions, it generates `CORS error`. It accesses the link being used when we deploy our functions.

`https://us-central1-talkfor-dev.cloudfunctions.net/v1-auth-updateUser`

- This is the link that was shown in the console

What I expected is that `us-central1-talkfor-dev.cloudfunctions.net` will be `localhost:5000` since we are using the local development.

Do you have any Idea why is it like this?

Answer (score 1):

Alex you understand that SSR mode is trying to render the website on the server. This can be your local running server instance, that means there is no `window` object for it to access location variable. Location is only accessible inside the browser. The SSR context is not in the browser, hence makes total sense.

[Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) here states.

[image: Location Object]

[Server vs Browser environments](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/server-side-rendering#server-vs-browser-environments) here states that

> Because you are in a Node.js environment... You do not have access to the window or document objects... You can however use window or document by using the beforeMount or mounted hooks.
> .

Why don't you try either of these,

- use these `beforeMount` and `mounted` hooks like this.

```js
beforeMount () {
  window.alert('hello');
}
mounted () {
  window.alert('hello');
}
```

- using the `process.client` environment variable

```js
if (process.client) {
  // Do your stuff here
  // I think this is what you are looking for.
}
```